# Linker error while including omniture library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

[image]

I am getting this error after including Omniture library.

I am not able to find "RegexKitLite", but it seems as if it is refrenced inside the omniture library.

I have set `other linker flags` and `library search path`, but still the problem persists.

This error does not come when I use `libOmnitureAppMeasurement-iPhoneSimulator.a`, it only comes when I use `libOmnitureAppMeasurement-iPhoneDevice`

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed by removing otherlinkerflags. Thanks.